# How users can create Teams online meetings from my application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to allow users of my application to create online meetings from my application and get `joinWebUrl` via Graph API. Some of the users and meeting participants have Microsoft accounts and some do not.

In order to achieve this, I have followed the steps below and could create online meetings. But I'm not sure, so please give me some advice if this is the right way.

1. I registered my application to my AAD account and granted the application the `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` permission.
2. I requested and got an access token.

   ```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/myAppTenatID/oauth2/v2.0/token
   ```
3. I created an access policy for my application, and granted me and Global.

   ```
   PowerShell    
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity online-policy -AppIds "myAppID"    
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName online-policy -Identity "myObjectID"    
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName online-policy -Global
   ```
4. I requested and retrieved `joinWebUrl` from the response.

   ```
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myObjectID/onlineMeetings
   ```

Will ALL users of my application be able to create online meetings this way? Please let me know if there are any steps I have missed or unnecessary.

Comment: The steps you are following are correct. In these cases, the user that the application acts on behalf of is identified as the meeting organizer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for the reply!
I am relieved to see your answer, it looks like I can create an application to create Teams online meetings.I've also checked the Docs you linked to.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you are following are correct. In these cases, the user that the application acts on behalf of is identified as the meeting organizer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy

Comment: Hi, @Prasad-MSFT . Is there a way to not specify an organizer?
I mean, my account will be invited to all the meetings created by my application in this way.

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be any way. Organizer will be part of those meetings

Comment: Hi, @Prasad-MSFT . I understand. I'm very sorry. Thank you very much.